# Is this homebrew entropic spear balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, weapons, balance, homebrew-review

I have created a magical entropic spear that I plan to give to the party when they reach roughly 10th level. Is this balanced?

> #### Entropic Spear
>
> *Weapon (spear), rare*
>
> This is a +2 magical weapon. On a critical hit, this spear does an extra 2d6 damage of a random type. Roll a d10 on
> the table below to determine the type:
>
> 1. Acid
> 2. Cold
> 3. Fire
> 4. Force
> 5. Lightning
> 6. Necrotic
> 7. Poison
> 8. Psychic
> 9. Radiant
> 10. Thunder
>
> This spear has 5 charges, regaining 1d4+1 charges at dawn. As a reaction, when an attack hits you, you can expend 1 or more charges to reduce the damage by 1d6 per charge spent. You can only reduce damage of a type that appears on the above table. If you use the last charge, roll a d20 after applying the effects of the item. On a 1, the spear crumbles into dust and cannot be repaired.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47068/discussion-between-jamie-brace-and-yakk).

Comment: I would suggest changing "This is a +2 magical weapon." to "This magic spear has a +2 bonus to attack and damage rolls made with it."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### It is balanced

Its magical properties are a bit better than a vanilla +2 rare weapon, but this can only be a spear.
Most characters would do higher DPR with a +2 Longsword, so I do not think it is too strong.

Comment: would requiring attunement make this any more or less balanced? In my game, I allowed a maximum of 3 attuned items.

Comment: less balanced, it is near perfect now, but will get weaker with attunement

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll leave it as it is and maybe just make it hard to find instead of essentially handing it to the party.

Answer (score 3):

### It's balanced, but you could make it very rare

Most characters by 10th level will have a +7 or +8 bonus to hit with regular weapons. Given that this spear gives an additional +2, it would give them a good hike on the bonus to hit, making it so that most creatures they confront would be hit 55-60% of the time. You also add the equivalent of a greatsword hit in damage die, but at least the type is random. It's properties are, I think, well offset by the limited number of charges.

Overall I think this is a balanced item, but you may want to make it very rare instead of rare.

Comment: a very rare competes against a +3 item, and this is _very_ far behind that

Comment: A vanilla +3 item is very rare, and I'd say this competes with that.